# How to match multiple "\n" in a string and replace it with single "\n"

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace multiple "\n"s and replace it with single "\n" in a given string

**Example**

```
const str = "THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n"
console.log(str.replaceAll(/some_regex/, '\n'));
```

**Output** `"THIS IS A TEXT \n THIS IS A TEXT \n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit, the solutions below makes less sense since you want 1 or more `\n`s to be replaced. So `/(\n)+/` should work for you

```js
const str = "THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\nTHIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n\n\n"
console.log(str.replaceAll(/(\n)+/g, 'FOO'));
```

---

You can use `/(\n){3,}/` to match the pattern repeating 3 times or more

```js
const str = "THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\nTHIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n\n\n"
console.log(str.replaceAll(/(\n){3,}/g, 'FOO'));
```

For 2 times or more

```js
const str = "THIS IS A TEXT \nTHIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n\n\n"
console.log(str.replaceAll(/(\n){2,}/g, 'FOO'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(/\n+/g, '\n\n')`

1. `\n+` - match 1 or more `\n`
2. `g` - globally

```js
const str = "THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n THIS IS A TEXT \n\n\n"
console.log(str.replace(/\n+/g, '\n\n'));
```

Build on that, ie.:

1. Use `\n\n+` for 2 or more consecutive `\n`
2. Use `\n\n\n+` for 3 or more consecutive `\n`

You might want to add an additional trimming of produced lines.

Comment: \n+ is actually one or more

Comment: what if I want to match two or more

Comment: Take a look at my last edit